# Proof of flat base change: reduction to affines

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand the proof of flat base change. I refer to https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02KH for the statement and the notation. The first line of the proof says:

> Namely, part (1) is local on $S′$ and hence we may assume $S$ and $S′$ are affine.

I understand that I can assume $S'$ to be affine. Indeed, the natural morphism
\begin{equation}
g^* R^i f_* F \to R^i f'_* F'
\end{equation}
is an isomorphism if and only if for any $u \colon U \to S'$ with $U$ affine we have that
\begin{equation}
u^* g^* R^i f_* F \to u^* R^i f'_* F'
\end{equation}
is an isomorphism. So, if we can prove flat base change with $S'$ affine, we can prove the general statement. However, I don't understand how we can assume also $S$ to be affine. Why and how is this possible?

Comment: Cover $S$ with open affines $\{U_i\}$, then refine the induced covering $\{g^{-1}(U_i)\}$ of $S'$ with a covering by open affines $g^{-1}(U_i) = \bigcup \{ V_{ij} \}$?